# Python Spark How to find cumulative sum by group using RDD API

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am new to spark programming. Need help with spark python program, where i have input data like this and want to get cumulative summary for each group. Appreciate if someone guide me on this.

## Input Data:

11,1,1,100

11,1,2,150

12,1,1,50

12,2,1,70

12,2,2,20

## Output Data Needed like this:

11,1,1,100

11,1,2,250 //(100+150)

12,1,1,50

12,2,1,70

12,2,2,90 // (70+20)

the code i tried:

```
def parseline(line):
    fields = line.split(",")
    f1 = float(fields[0])
    f2 = float(fields[1])
    f3 = float(fields[2])
    f4 = float(fields[3])
    return (f1, f2, f3, f4)

input = sc.textFile("FIle:///...../a.dat")
line = input.map(parseline)
linesorted = line.sortBy(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], x[2]))
runningpremium = linesorted.map(lambda y: (((y[0], y[1]),     y[3])).reduceByKey(lambda accum, num: accum + num)

for i in runningpremium.collect():
      print i
```

Comment: The most simple answer will  be: use DataFrames with window functions. Code will be much easier

Comment: The simplest* of course ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, trying to do without dataframe if possible at all.

Answer (score 2):

As in the comment, you can use window function to do the cumulative sum here on Spark Dataframe. First, we can create an example dataframe with dummie columns `'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'`

```
ls = [(11,1,1,100), (11,1,2,150), (12,1,1,50), (12,2,1,70), (12,2,2,20)]
ls_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(ls)
df = spark.createDataFrame(ls_rdd, schema=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

You can partition by column `a` and `b` then order by column `c`. Then, apply the `sum` function over the column `d` at the end

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

w = Window.partitionBy([df['a'], df['b']]).orderBy(df['c'].asc())
df_cumsum = df.select('a', 'b', 'c', func.sum(df.d).over(w).alias('cum_sum'))
df_cumsum.sort(['a', 'b', 'c']).show() # simple sort column
```

**Output**

```
+---+---+---+-------+
|  a|  b|  c|cum_sum|
+---+---+---+-------+
| 11|  1|  1|    100|
| 11|  1|  2|    250|
| 12|  1|  1|     50|
| 12|  2|  1|     70|
| 12|  2|  2|     90|
+---+---+---+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Dataframe API**:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StringType, LongType,StructField
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
sc= spark.sparkContext

rdd = sc.parallelize([(11, 100),(11, 150),(12, 50),(12, 70),(12, 20)])

schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType()),
    StructField("amount", LongType())
    ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

df.registerTempTable("amount_table")
df.show();
df2 = spark.sql("SELECT id,amount, sum(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY amount) as cumulative_sum FROM amount_table")
df2.show()
```

**Using RDD API** try this:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(11, 1, 2, 100), (11, 2, 1, 150), (12, 1, 2, 50), (12, 1, 3, 70), (12, 3, 4, 20)])

def get_key_value(rec):
    # for grouping as key value
    return rec[0], rec[1:]

from itertools import accumulate

def cumsum(values):
    return [k[0]+[k[1]] for k in zip([[i[0],i[1]] for i in values], accumulate([i[2] for i in values]))]

print(rdd.map(get_key_value).collect()) # output after get_key_value
print(rdd.map(get_key_value).groupByKey().mapValues(cumsum).flatMapValues(lambda x:x).map(lambda x: [x[0]]+x[1]).collect())
```

Output:

```
[(11, (1, 2, 100)), (11, (2, 1, 150)), (12, (1, 2, 50)), (12, (1, 3, 70)), (12, (3, 4, 20))]
[[11, 1, 2, 100], [11, 2, 1, 250], [12, 1, 2, 50], [12, 1, 3, 120], [12, 3, 4, 140]]
```

**A simpler example** involving only two columns( 2 values in each record)

```
rdd=sc.parallelize([(11, 100), (11, 150), (12, 50), (12, 70), (12, 20)])
from itertools import accumulate

def cumsum(values):
    return list(accumulate(values))
print(rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(cumsum).collect())
print(rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(cumsum).flatMapValues(lambda x:x).collect())
```

Output:

```
[(11, [100, 250]), (12, [50, 120, 140])]
[(11, 100), (11, 250), (12, 50), (12, 120), (12, 140)]
```

Comment: i am using lower version of spark where data frame is not yet available. Hence cant accept your answer. But if you have the solution in RDD style please share , will be appreciated.

Comment: @RoyR I have added RDD api usage as well

Answer (score 0):

```
rdd=sc.parallelize([(11, 100), (11, 150), (12, 50), (12, 70), (12, 20)])

print(rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(lambda x: sum(list(x))).collect())
```

groupByKey() groups the rdd array (think of it as array of tuples) by the first element of each tuple and result will be a list of tuples with first element to be the key (the grouping element) and the second element will be rdd object containing the grouped values for each key, so we have to map this object to a list then summing this list gives us the cumulative sum for each group.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.